# How do I add a row to a mysql result set for use as a prompt in an html selectbox?

Tags: mysql, sql, append, resultset, drop-down-menu

I'm running a SQL query that returns two columns and X number of rows. The two columns are the value and text for a select box:

```
value: 1 text: Boston
value: 2 text: NYC
value: N text: Whatever
```

I'd like to add another row to the result set ***at the time the query is done*** so the results I get back would be something like:

```
value: 0 text: Select a city
value: 1 text: Boston
value: 2 text: NYC
value: N text: Whatever
```

I don't want to add the new row to the DB, just to the result set. The reason I want to do this is that the query is used by a CMS and I want to avoid hacking into it. I've seen some solutions involving a UNION or JOIN but I would rather not store the text elsewhere.

This is my query right now:

```
SELECT id AS value, city AS text FROM #__cities
```

Is there anything like?

```
SELECT id AS value, city AS text FROM #__cities *APPEND id=0, formal_name='Select a city'*
```

Comment: What scripting/programming language are you processing the select statement?  You could add the text without any SQL interaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to store the text anywhere (except for the query, of course)

```
SELECT 0, 'Select a city:'
UNION ALL
SELECT id AS value, city AS text FROM #__cities
```

Comment: I'd suggest a `UNION ALL` vs a `UNION` in this case.

Comment: Great, thanks! One quick follow up, if I want to use an ORDER BY clause, I would either need to alias the data in the first SELECT or swap the SELECTS.

Comment: You want to sort by name, but also want this item to come first?

Comment: Yes, I used: `(SELECT 0 AS value, 'Select a city' AS text) UNION ALL (SELECT id AS value, city AS text FROM #__cities) ORDER BY value!=0,text` (I could have swapped the SELECTS too, as mentioned above.)